# Can't mock the navigator.language

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I'm currently adding unit test for some of shard utils functions. I'm kinda new to unit testing. Currently having hard time to mock some global object. Is there any way to mock/update value of `navigator.language`? It is always returning `en-US`. I tried the Object.defineProperty and different jest mock objects. Didn't work.

The thing is, if I `console.log(navigator.language)` in the test, it will show me mocked value, but util function is not seeing that value.

Here is the code.

```
//utils.js

export function getLang() {
  if (navigator.languages) return navigator.languages[0];
  return navigator.language;
}
```

```
//utils.spec.ts

describe('Navigator', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });


  //Error - Failing
  it('should return exact response language if there is one', () => {
    jest.spyOn(navigator, 'language', 'get').mockImplementation(() => 'en-fr');
    expect(getLang()).toBe('en-fr');
  });



  // Successful - passing
  it('should return 1st language if there array of languages', () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(navigator, 'languages', 'get')
      .mockImplementation(() => ['en-fr', 'en-US', 'en']);
    expect(getLang()).toBe('en-fr');
  });
});
```

```
    Expected: "en-fr"
    Received: "en-US"

      25 |     jest.spyOn(navigator, 'language', 'get').mockImplementation(() => 'en-fr');
      26 |     const lang = getLang();
    > 27 |     expect(lang).toBe('en-fr');
         |                  ^
      28 |   });
```

```
//package.json:

"jest": "^27.5.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getLang` function requires that you mock both `navigator.languages` and `navigator.language`.

In your case, you'd have to mock `navigator.languages` to return `undefined` or null to test that `it("returns navigator.language when navigator.languages is undefined"`

Comment: Oh man! Thanks for the tip. Literally didn't even see it. My idiot logic. :) 


Now it is fixed after mocking it. Very big thanks to you man :) Now I can breath easily.